# How to speed up SQLAlchemy query?

Tags: python, performance, sqlalchemy

I try to use SQLAlchemy to fetch columns from a database then plot them, but it is very slow the way I am doing it now.

My table:

```
class Obs(Base):

__tablename__ = "Obs"

id = Column(Integer, primary_key= True)
obs_date = Column(Date, primary_key= True)
temp = Column(Float)
temp_i= Column(Float)
```

It looks like this:

```
ID    Date          temp    temp_i
-----------------------------------
3111   2010-10-10   0.10       0.11
3256   2010-10-10   0.11       0.21
3111   2011-10-11   1.12       0.11
3256   2011-10-11   2.21       0.51
```

What I want to do is to filter out for a given ID, then plot the Date-Temp pairs. So my filtered table should look like this:

```
ID    Date          temp    temp_i
 -----------------------------------
 3111   2010-10-10   0.10       0.11
 3111   2011-10-11   1.12       0.11
```

I tried the following functions to filter out for temp given an id:

```
def getObs(id, from_date, to_date):
    query = session.query(Obs.temp).filter(Obs.id == id). \
        filter(and_(Obs.obs_date >= from_date, Obs.obs_date <= to_date))
    tempList = []
    for row in query:
        tempList.append(row.temp)
    return tempList
```

It works, but very slow, for a 5000 element list it takes like 45 seconds to run. Is there any way to speed it up?

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to speed up SQLAlchemy, or how to speed up the database's evaluation of the SQL that SQLAlchemy generates?

Comment: While SqlAlchemy works well, I never really liked it for highly optimized code.  The reasoning for this is that it is an abstraction, removed from what raw sql would do.  Ideally, the purpose is that it will take your data and convert it into a query string.  If you need something specific, it might be better to develop your own raw query string, which would develop a more custom join statement.  That's just what i have noticed for my dev scenarios and not necessarily an all encompassing answer.

Comment: @Fallenreaper, ...funny, the thing I *like* about SQLAlchemy is that, compared to most ORMs, it's a very thin and transparent abstraction layer, which makes it easy to generate the exact SQL you want. (Indeed, that the "query builder" *isn't* an ORM at all and isn't bound to the idea of having one is part of the value).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i do agree it is a thin abstraction to some extent, but when developing left inner joins in accordance with SqlAlchemy, it doesnt do it, but filters a standard join, creating a higher runtime.  Now, that is taking into account that maybe I am not developing the python statements correctly.  I default back to what I know, which is vanilla sql for sqlite and oracle.  Maybe that is my flaw.  Always interested in learning more though

Comment: @user137425 if you are copying 5000 elements from a table to a list... you are doing it correctly.  If you are trying to optimize by filtering, creating more complex joins or the like, you would then need some adjusting to the design.  I feel there might be some factors you might not be presenting to us in entirity.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Getting this 'query' object is pretty fast. What is slow is to extract from it the data and put it into an other list. 
I don't know any other way to plot the query object results.

Comment: @user137425, so, what I'd suggest is that you print the query as text, and try running it directly on your database. If the query has the same performance when you run it direct on the database, and is written the same way you'd write it by hand, then this isn't SQLAlchemy's problem.

Comment: @user137425, ...by contrast, if in running the query by hand you come up with a way you can modify it that'll significantly improve performance, well, you've got something you can use to [edit] this into a clearer, better-defined question ("How do I generate Query X instead of Query Y in SQLAlchemy?"). Right now it's just too broad -- whatever's making your query slow is going to be a combination of factors above and beyond the information available to us here.

Comment: Most likely you don't have an index on `Obs.obs_date` or `Spot.name`. The line `query =` is fast because it doesn't actually execute the query. `for row in query` is when it actually executes the query, and it's slow not because it takes a long time to transfer 5000 floats, nor is it because it takes a long time to append those numbers to a list; it's because the query itself is slow. And the #1 reason why a query is slow is not having the appropriate indices.

Comment: @univerio Thanks, can you elaborate on what do you mean 'having the proper indices' ?

Comment: If you want your queries to run fast, you need to set up your tables to have indices that match your access pattern. If you need to query on a range condition (< and >) on the column `Obs.obs_date`, for example, you need a B-tree index on that column. It looks like you have some errors in your models. In particular, it's not clear what the join condition between `Obs` and `Spot` is. Regardless, you can start by adding an index on `Obs.obs_date`: `CREATE INDEX ix_obs_obs_date ON obs(obs_date);`.

Comment: @univerio I could modify my code, so I don't have to use join now, but it still takes the same amount of time.

Comment: @user137425, ...again, focus on building fast SQL (probably just by adding indexes to your database to make the existing queries run faster). Starting from the Python code is the wrong direction from which to approach the problem.

Comment: Hmm. The decision to use a compound primary key here is interesting. It means that the real DDL contains an order -- one of the two components comes before the other in the implicit index -- but we can't tell from what's given here what that order is.

Comment: Also, it seems like a very... questionable... idea. Do you **really** want to allow two entries to have the same ID number as long as they have different dates, or the same date as long as they have different IDs?

Comment: what database are you using? different database handle compound keys differently.

Comment: ...do you actually **need** the numeric id? If you took it out, then your primary key index would be more likely to be helpful for your immediate query.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I updated the question, I hope it is clearer now. For me it seems a very simple task, and my solution works, but I think it shouldn't be this slow.
I don't have the right to write into this database, I have to query the tables as they are.

Comment: If the tables aren't written to allow them to be queried efficiently (and part of that is building correct indexes), you need to fix the database. There's nothing the client-side code can do. (If there's no usable index, then the server will need to run a full-table scan and compare each and every row to see if its date is inside the relevant range; this is by its nature a slow and expensive operation).

Comment: (If you want to convince me that it's a client-side problem, I told you many times how to do that despite the request being repeatedly ignored: Ask SQLAlchemy to print the SQL it's using to run the query, run that SQL directly against the database, and provide both timings).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are right, if i execute the raw sql it takes the same time.

Comment: Well, there you are. If you can come up with faster SQL, we can help you write SQLAlchemy to model it, but I'd be very surprised if you *could* without fixing things on the database end.